# XSLT 2.0: build a tree from linear <h1/> - <h2/> - <h3/> tags system

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am trying to figure out how to buid, in XSLT 2.0, a node tree from a system of header tags (<h1> etc.)
Normally, in xhtml, header tags are not nested. To build a table of contents, it would be handier to have a tree structure in XSLT.
I suspect I could use recursion to do it.
So my XML file has xhtml-style header tags, and I want to build an xhtml file containing a nested table of contents, using <ol> or <ul>.

```
<h1>header 1.0</h1>
  <h2>header 2.1</h2>
  <h2>header 2.2</h2>
    <h3>header 3.1</h3>
    <h3>header 3.2</h3>
  <h2>header 2.3</h2>
</h1>
```

result:

```
<ol>
   <li> header 1.0
      <ol>
        <li>header 2.1</li>
        <li>header 2.2
           <ol>
              <li>header 3.1</li>
              <li>header 3.2></li>
           </ol>
        </li>
        <li>header 2.3</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
 </ol>
```

So far I have something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="toc">
<xsl:apply-templates select="h1"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="h[123]">
<xsl:copy>
      <!-- something with name() here? -->
  <xsl:if test="next() ne  .">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="next()"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(I left out the list stuff, for clarity)
Of course, it does not work. I could use some help, here...

Comment: `match` takes xpath expressions, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd approach this kind of thing with `for-each-group`, though it would get a bit repetitive if you have more than three levels of headings:

```
<ol>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="h1|h2|h3" group-starting-with="h1">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- . is the group leader (the h1) -->
      <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
        <ol>
          <!-- current-group() except . is the rest (h2s and h3s) -->
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ."
                              group-starting-with="h2">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- . is the h2 -->
              <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
                <ol>
                  <!-- current-group() except . will all be h3s (if any) -->
                  <xsl:for-each select="current-group() except .">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </ol>
              </xsl:if>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ol>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</ol>
```

Thinking further about this, you could make the whole thing recursive to reduce the repetition

```
<xsl:template name="toc">
  <xsl:param name="nodes" />
  <xsl:param name="level" />
  <ol>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes"
                group-starting-with="*[local-name() = concat('h',$level)]">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
          <xsl:call-template name="toc">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="current-group() except ." />
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </ol>
</xsl:template>
```

and start the process with

```
<xsl:call-template name="toc">
  <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="h1|h2|h3" />
  <xsl:with-param name="level" select="1" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: How very elegant! Very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: In the line "group-starting-with=", can I use the tag name of $nodes[1] ? Would save me a param...

Comment: Yes, I can: <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-starting-with="*[local-name() = name($nodes[1])]">. No need anymore for the $level parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your input XHTML is not well-formed. I will assume you actually have a legal XHTML document. I changed the numbering a bit so it's easier to follow. Suppose this represent the relevant parts of the document you have:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>header 1</h1>
    <h2>header 1.1</h2>
    <h2>header 1.2</h2>
    <h3>header 1.2.1</h3>
    <h3>header 1.2.2</h3>
    <h2>header 1.3</h2>
    <h3>header 1.3.1</h3>
    <h1>header 2</h1>
    <h2>header 2.1</h2>
    <h2>header 2.2</h2>
    <h3>header 2.2.1</h3>
    <h3>header 2.3.2</h3>
    <h2>header 2.3</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

You have to treat `h1`, `h2` and `h3` as different levels, and create nested lists if they have sublevels. This is an alternative stylesheet which produces the result you are expecting:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="html">
        <ol><xsl:apply-templates select="h1"/></ol>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h3">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h1">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-sublevel">
                <xsl:with-param name="sub-levels" 
                                select="following::h2[preceding::h1[1] is current()]"/>
            </xsl:call-template></li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h2">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-sublevel">
                <xsl:with-param name="sub-levels" 
                                select="following::h3[preceding::h2[1] is current()]"/>
            </xsl:call-template></li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="add-sublevel">
        <xsl:param name="sub-levels"/>
        <xsl:if test="$sub-levels">
            <ol><xsl:apply-templates select="$sub-levels"/></ol>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result will be:

```
<ol>
   <li>header 1
      <ol>
         <li>header 1.1</li>
         <li>header 1.2
            <ol>
               <li>header 1.2.1</li>
               <li>header 1.2.2</li>
            </ol>
         </li>
         <li>header 1.3
            <ol>
               <li>header 1.3.1</li>
            </ol>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li>header 2
      <ol>
         <li>header 2.1</li>
         <li>header 2.2
            <ol>
               <li>header 2.2.1</li>
               <li>header 2.3.2</li>
            </ol>
         </li>
         <li>header 2.3</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```